# Can I scroll a TEXTAREA to a specific line number using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a multi-line `TEXTAREA` element.

Given an integer which represents a specific line number in the string of text contained in that `TEXTAREA` (as delimited by a newline in the string, not a textwrap in the element -- so *actual* line, not visual line of the string in the `TEXTAREA`), can I scroll the `TEXTAREA` to that line number using JavaScript?

Most scrolling seems to be by pixels, and this doesn't work (even if you assume whatever line-height you have is accurate) because long lines wrap, which means the actual line number doesn't match the visual line number.

Comment: you should recreate your text with divs for rows with the same styles as the textarea and get the bounding rectangle of the row of interest

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Focus on Line</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="textarea" autofocus style="height:200px;">
0123456781
0123456782
0123456783
0123456784
0123456785
0123456786
0123456787
0123456788
0123456789
0123456710
0123456711
0123456712
0123456713
0123456714
0123456715
0123456716
0123456717
0123456718
0123456719
0123456720
    </textarea>
    <button onClick="go(5)">Go Line 10</button>
    <button onClick="focusToTxt()">Focus</button>
    </body> </html>
```

Javascript:

```
 var startLength = 0; 

function go(line)
{
    function lineFocus(textarea,line) { 
        var lines = textarea.value.split('\n');

        if (line >= 0 && line < lines.length) { 
        var lineHeight = textarea.scrollHeight / lines.length;

        textarea.scrollTop = lineHeight * line;

        }


        for(var index=0; index < lines.length; index++)
        {
            if(index==(line-1))
            { 
                break;
            }
            startLength+=lines[index].length+1;

        }
    }

    var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');  
    lineFocus(textarea,line);
}

function focusToTxt(){
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');  

    textarea.focus({focusVisible :true});

    textarea.selectionStart=startLength;

    textarea.selectionEnd=startLength+1;
    startLength=0;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6xbfrzqg/1/

Note: I create two buttons, one for move the scrool and other to move the focus. But you can use the both, but you need run the second function after some time to release the GUI to update the scrollbar before the focus. Try using the code below (not work into JSFiddle)

```
setTimeout(200,focusToTxt());
```